# Joint spectral radius of $\{M,M^T\}$

Tags: matrices, semigroups-and-monoids, spectral-radius

Let $F$ be a bounded subset of ${\bf M}_n({\mathbb C})$. G.-C. Rota & G. Strang defined the joint spectral radius of $F$ as follows. For $k\ge1$, denote $F_k$ the set of all products of $k$ elements of $F$. Set $\|F_k\|$ the supremum of some matrix norm over $F_k$. The sequence $\|F_k\|^{\frac1k}$ converges to its lower bound, denoted $\rho(F)$. This joint spectral radius does not depend upon the choice of the norm.

> I am interested in the case where $F$ consists in two elements $M$ and $M^*$. I suspect that $\rho(F)$ equals $\rho(M^*M)^{\frac12}$, that is $\|M\|_2$ where $\|\cdot\|_2$ is the standard operator norm over the Hermitian space ${\mathbb C}^n$.

I am especially interested in the case where $F=\{L,U\}$ with 
$$L=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix},\qquad U=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}.$$
This example occurs in the study of the set $S$ of $2\times 2$ matrices with entries in $\mathbb N$ and of unit determinant. It is known that $S$ is the monoid generated by $F$, and that there are no relations between $L$ and $U$. In other words, every element $M\in S$ is a unique word in the alphabet $F$. If the claim above is correct, then every element of length $k$ satisfies $\|M\|_2\le\phi^k$, where $\phi$ is the golden ratio.

Comment: $\| F_2\|^{1/2}$ is the golden ratio, and for $k$ even $\| F_k\|^{1/k}$ is at least the golden ratio (taking $(LU)^k$). The same sequence for $k$ a power of two decreases so it is actually equal to the golden ratio. Then it is easy to see that the answer is yes

Comment: as Yuval says you can indeed start with $k=1$ which is even simpler

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your suspicion is correct. The lower bound is obtained by simply alternating $M$ and its transpose. The upper bound follows from sub-multiplicativity of the norm and the  fact that 
the operator norm $\|M\|_2$ equals the top singular value of $M$, namely $\rho(M^*M)^{\frac12}$.

Comment: Of course. I have been rather naive !